# SimpleExoPlayer doesn't show right duration of audio

Tags: android, duration, exoplayer2.x

I realized that when I open audio in Windows Media Player, it displays the durations as 2:39. However, SimpleExoPlayerView's duration is set as 2:40. In other examples it even add 5-6 seconds more to duration. Why is that?